# Retrieve consent from Iubenda

Tags: javascript, saas

I've installed the Iubenda Consent Solution JS SDK, and it appears to work. Once a user indicates their consent by scrolling or dismissing the notice, the banner goes away and, presumably, the consent is stored in the Iubenda system.

Once the consent is recorded, one must be able to retrieve it and Iubenda says this can be done using either the HTTP API or by JavaScript, however these methods are not well documented.

Retrieving the consent via the HTTP API is partially described on the Iubenda website (https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/6469-guide-to-the-consent-solution) and this method is given:

```
GET https://consent.iubenda.com/consent/:id
```

Obviously this is useless if we do not know the consent id and if there is no way of revoking the consent.

How can I use JavaScript to retrieve the consent?

I plan to install the SDK on a 'privacy settings' page where the user can review and if desired revoke the consent(s).

The good folks at Iubenda appear to be overwhelmed by requests for help through their primitive ticket system, so I am asking anyone with experience to please help out!

*NB*: sorry but I am unable to add the new tag *Iubenda* and the tag *GDPR* is not allowed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrea from iubenda here.

The iubenda Consent Solution is meant to be used to store proof of consent in context like online forms, where you collect consent for data processing activities like newsletter subscription, profiling etc.

The iubenda Cookie Solution is used to collect consent for the installation of cookies. On the topic of storing consent collected using the Cookie Solution, read our article here: https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/5525-cookies-and-eu-data-law-gdpr-requirements (under "Proof of consent vs Records of consent")

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I am using Iubenda only for AdSense. Do I need the Consent Solution in that case?

Comment: There was supposed to be a difference between the current version of AdSense and a new 'non-personalized' AdSense, apparently released only from 25 May. Here is a link explaining the difference https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9007336 Can you comment on the implications for Iubenda users? Bearing in mind of course that we must absolutely not discuss GDPR legal matters here ;-p

Comment: looks like Google still requires "cookie consent", no matter whether it's used in fully-fledged mode or not.